# Problem #5 in SQLZOO's "Window functions" tutorial

Tags: sql

I have been struggling with problem #5 of SQLZOO's "[Window functions](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Window_functions)" tutorial. The tutorial uses the table "ge," which includes general election results in the UK for 2015 and 2017. "ge" includes the fields yr, firstName, lastName, constituency, party, and votes. Problem #5 asks the learner to show the parties that won for each Edinburgh constituency in 2017. Earlier on, the tutorial notes that Edinburgh constituencies are numbered S14000021 to S14000026. Below is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT constituency, party
FROM ge x
WHERE constituency BETWEEN 'S14000021' AND 'S14000026'
AND yr = 2017
AND votes > ALL
(SELECT votes FROM ge y
WHERE y.constituency = x.constituency
AND y.party != x.party)
GROUP BY constituency
```

My result is mostly correct, but omits constituencies S14000021 and S14000026. I wondered at first if BETWEEN might not be inclusive, but toying with that didn't solve the problem. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `rank()`  function

```
select  constituency,party from 
(
SELECT constituency,party, votes , 
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY constituency order by votes desc) rn
  FROM ge
 WHERE constituency BETWEEN 'S14000021' AND 'S14000026'
   AND yr  = 2017
ORDER BY constituency,votes DESC
) TAB WHERE rn =1
```

In windowing functions, we define a partition clause for a particular group (i.e constituency in our case and order by for sorting of rows).

`RANK()` function assigns a rank for each record within a group and starts from 1 for the next group.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. One thing I don't understand is what "TAB" does in the last line. Can you explain that?

Comment: It's an alias for subquery.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this using WITH AS. The first table, t1, retrieves the constituency, party, votes, and partitions votes (using `RANK()` as another person suggested) by each constituency.

```html
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT constituency,
           party,
           votes,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY constituency ORDER BY votes DESC) AS pos
    FROM ge
    WHERE yr=2017)

SELECT constituency, party
FROM t1
WHERE pos=1 AND (constituency BETWEEN 'S14000021' AND 'S14000026');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT constituency, party
FROM ge x
WHERE constituency BETWEEN 'S14000021' AND 'S14000026'
AND yr = 2017
AND votes >= ALL
(SELECT votes FROM ge y
WHERE y.constituency = x.constituency
AND yr = 2017)
GROUP BY constituency
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: this was inspired by first solution which was getting partial results,
although approach was correct.
it was not working as condition for sub-query must include yr = 2017 as well
, also since there must be only one winner i.e candidate with max votes 
condition  y.party != x.party can be excluded with >= condition

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT constituency,party, votes,
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY constituency ORDER BY votes DESC) as posn
  FROM ge
 WHERE constituency in ('S14000021','S14000022','S14000023','S14000024','S14000025','S14000026') and yr = 2017
ORDER BY posn asc , constituency
```

Comment: This is not correct as it does not select the position

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT constituency,party, votes,
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY  constituency ORDER BY votes DESC) as posn
  FROM ge
 WHERE constituency BETWEEN 'S14000021' AND 'S14000026'
   AND yr  = 2017
ORDER BY posn asc , constituency
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT constituency, party from(
SELECT constituency, party, votes, 
MAX(votes) OVER (PARTITION BY constituency ORDER BY votes DESC) as max_votes
  FROM ge
 WHERE constituency BETWEEN 'S14000021' AND 'S14000026' AND yr  = 2017) a
where votes = max_votes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
party, count(*)
FROM
(
SELECT party, rank() over (partition by constituency order by votes desc) as rank
FROM ge
WHERE constituency LIKE 'S%'
AND yr  = 2017
)l
WHERE l.rank=1
GROUP BY party
ORDER BY party
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT constituency, party, FROM
     (
     SELECT constituency, party ,votes,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY constituency ORDER BY votes DESC) AS pos
     FROM ge
     WHERE yr=2017  AND constituency BETWEEN 'S14000021' AND 'S14000026'
     ) t1   
 WHERE t1.pos=1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.