# When should I add TAB for subqueries in SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariasql

I am practicing SQL in SQLZOO and having trouble understanding the solution to the question #5: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Window_functions

I copied the description of the table and question from another user @crowtherl

This question uses table "ge" which includes general election results in the UK for 2015 and 2017. "ge" includes the fields yr, firstName, lastName, constituency, party, and votes. Problem #5 asks the learner to show the parties that won for each Edinburgh constituency in 2017. Earlier on, the tutorial notes that Edinburgh constituencies are numbered S14000021 to S14000026.

Solution: [Problem #5 in SQLZOO's "Window functions" tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923287/problem-5-in-sqlzoos-window-functions-tutorial)

Particularly about this code:

```
  select  constituency,party from 
(
SELECT constituency,party, votes , 
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY constituency order by votes desc) rn
  FROM ge
 WHERE constituency BETWEEN 'S14000021' AND 'S14000026'
   AND yr  = 2017
ORDER BY constituency,votes DESC
) TAB WHERE rn =1
```

If I run the query above without "TAB" in the outer query, I get: "Error:
Every derived table must have its own alias."

After searching around I can't find a good answer explaining why I need to add 'TAB'. Is this something particular to MariaDB? Does anyone know? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard SQL I believe. Just to be clear, "TAB" is an alias for the table resulting from the second SELECT i.e. the one inside the parentheses. It can be any name you choose (e.g. "T1", "Extract" or "Whatever"), it doesn't have to be "TAB".

Comment: Thank you, but why do I have to use an alias for this query to run? Does the subquery have to have an alias?

Comment: Yes, the subquery has to have an alias.  It's just part of the SQL grammar I guess.  I remember being puzzled by this too, when I first encountered it!